# Estimated Taxes and Solar Tax Credit

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-credit, estimated-taxes

Can I apply the anticipated solar tax credit for my system that was installed in 2023 to my Form 1040-ES estimated tax payments (i.e. lowering them by that amount) without incurring an underpayment penalty, or does the credit get applied after the penalty is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I did not see this until after I posted the question, but it looks like the answer is in [this comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/137322/17754), and it is Yes, I can lower my estimated tax payments.

Comment: The proper way is to either delete the question altogether or to mark it as duplicate